# Give each element a unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking through post but cannot  seem to solve this last problem of how to give each element a unique id for example childsAge1, childsAge2 etc

```
for (var u = 0; u < 16; u++) ;

            var container = $('<div />');
            for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                container.append('<div>\n' +
                    '<select name="childsAge">    \n' +
                    '<option value="0">Less than 1</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="1">1</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="2">2</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="3">3</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="4">4</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="5">5</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="6">6</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="7">7</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="8">8</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="9">9</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="10">10</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="11">11</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="12">12</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="13">13</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="14">14</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="15">15</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="16">16</option>\n' +
                    '<option value="17">17</option>\n' +
                    '</select>\n' +
                    '</div>');
            }
            $('#dvChildren').html(container);
```

As you can see, I can create the number of dropdownlists that i require based on the value of

```
$('#SelectedChildrenValue').change(function() {
            var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

But I cannot seem to work out how to add the unique id, everything I have tried has not work, looking at other posts and trying their examples has also not work. Am I missing something simple.

Any help would be appreciated

---

Solved problem, I should have used `<select name="childsAge' +i+ '">`

Comment: Why don't you trust the `i` in your loop? ^^

Comment: Why do your elements need an id?

Comment: What does the first loop do?

Comment: Hi Jack, the 1st loop was just one of the ways I was trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try like

```
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            container.append('<div>\n' +
                '<select name="childsAge" id="childsAge'+i+'">    \n' +
```

Comment: Hi Gautam3164, I tried that before but did not work, childsAge=1&childsAge=2

Answer (score 1):

Try this after setting the `dvChildren` html content and outside the for loop:

```
var $select = $("#dvChildren select");
$select.attr('id', function (index) {
    return 'childsAge' + (index + 1);
});
```

For more information, see this [**blog post**](http://jquerytipsntricks.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/set-unique-id-for-multiple-elements-using-jquery/).

Comment: id is a property, not an attribute.